# Is it possible to Trigger Pop-up in select element using Semantic-UI

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I tried popup in button,input using semantic-ui and it works totally fine, but when i tried it in select it doesnt work. any idea why?

> Here is my Html code:

```
      <div class="field">
        <label>Machine No.</label>
        <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="machine_no" name="machine_no">
         <option selected value="">Select Machine No.</option>
         <option  value="1">1</option>
         <option  value="2">2</option>
         </select>
      </div>
```

> Here is my JS code:

```
   $('#machine_no').popup({
     inline     : true,
     hoverable  : true,
     on         : 'hover',
     position   : 'top center',
     delay: {
     show: 100,
     hide: 300
     },
     title: 'testing'

   });
```

Comment: it works fine to me..  what does your console says? maybe you are missing some scripts to include? check out this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9eqxa1s0/)

Comment: this is weird. your demo is fine. i tried it but the popup doesnt work the console has no warning or error.

Comment: i figured this out why it didnt work, because i have this code: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    on: 'hover'
  });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the solution to this problem is by removing this code:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
on: 'hover'
});
```

> Here is Html code:

```
 <div class="field">
    <label>Machine No.</label>
    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="machine_no" name="machine_no">
     <option selected value="">Select Machine No.</option>
     <option  value="1">1</option>
     <option  value="2">2</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

> here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready({
    $('#machine_no').popup({
    inline     : true,
    hoverable  : true,
    on         : 'hover',
    position   : 'top center',
    delay: {
    show: 100,
    hide: 300
    },
    title: 'testing'

   });
});
```